# Resigning: How to phrase email and what to say when sending email to all colleagues when leaving?

Tags: colleagues, email, offices, resignation

I will be leaving my current job soon, I already handed my notice in however I asked for it to be kept low key as I didn't want the whole office and my colleagues ask me why I was leaving etc (I don't enjoy the job and don't think its for me). So I have been told by the manager I need to let the office know now so they can start recruitment process.

I will be sending an email to all my colleagues letting them know I will be leaving soon. I would like some guidance on how to phrase this email. I'm sure it doesn't have to be formal, at the same time I want it to be short and sweet.

Comment: Have you secured a new job?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not an e-mail writing service

Comment: I haven't secured a new job. Although I did apply for another job which is the lowest skilled job in the company. I'm not sure how to avoid answering this question. There are other things I want to do too. Such as travelling the world. How do I make this sound positive?

Comment: @K.Dee - It seems strange you have to let the office know, you are leaving, instead of the manager.  *You are not required to explain the reasons you are leaving.*

Answer (score 6):

So just keep it short and sweet.

> Hi all.
>
> Unfortunately I will be leaving <company name> soon - my last day is <whenever>. It's been a pleasure working with you all and I hope our paths cross again in the future.
>
> If any of you do want to say in contact with me, [ give details of your phone number / LinkedIn / Facebook / etc here ].
>
> Thanks,
>
> K. Dee

The second paragraph is obviously optional, but keep the platitudes in the first paragraph even if you don't really mean them.

Comment: Drop 'unfortuantely'.

Comment: @Brandin curiosity, why drop Unfortunately? I would have use it also.

Comment: @SebastienDErrico Try removing it and then re-read it. It is short, to the point and positive. Unfortunately 'unfortunately' just starts things off negative.

Answer (score 0):

I would not write 
"unfortunatly" or "sorry" or anything if you don´t feel that way.
Try to find a positive phrase that concentrates on your personal growth like "find new challanges" etc. 
Thank you co-workers for working with you.

Then, get the mail signed-off by the Manager before sending - it´s easy to introduce unwanted subtext in these kind of Situations.